# how to repair ubuntu systems without losing current configuration

Tags: 14.04

I don't know what kind of wrong modification I made to my system,but for now even the `wine` package can't be installed correctly. using aptitude suggest me to install hundreds of new packages while removing more than 300 packages. that is so weird and nobody can help me to figure out the key point.

I decide to reinstall my system, however, it take me so long time to configure current system, many config files I don't want to write them again. so is there anyway to recover the default installation packages only, or just keep all my settings while reinstall the whole system ?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, I don't know when things come to such a situation. everything is fine, I can install a lot stuff without any problem. it seems to be when I want to install packages relate to graphics, there are always dependencies problems.
I ask around, nobody knows what happened. I just want to give up. it's a problem impossible to figure out.

people talk about using aptitude to resolve conflicts, but my aptitude suggest me to remove more than 300 packages include xinit, Ubuntu-desktop which is obviously crazy suggestion.

reinstallation is the only thing I can rely on now.

Comment: Did theese problems come after you try to upgrade? What ubuntu are you using now?

Comment: I installed a lot packages everyday, the true reason can't be traced. Failing to install wine today just uncovered the problem, but don't know which package caused it.

Comment: Seems like driver packages are messing with dependencies. Maybe you have multiple drivers installed?